# jQuery Event Listener for JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way to add an event listener/handler to a JavaScript object? Preferably using JQuery.

Such as:

```
var foo;
$(foo).bind('change', function() {
   alert("Foo has changed!");
 });
```

I have tried this, but nothing seems to happen. Does this only work with DOM elements?

EDIT:
I need an event fired every time that the audio or video tags throw an error. Originally, I was using an interval to check whether or not the error, `media.error`, object was null, but this uses excess processing power and I would like to avoid it.

EDIT 2: Apparently I was going about it wrong, easiest way I found was to add the `onerror` property to the video/audio tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Cheeso that it's more important for you to state what you actually want to do, however one workaround for your specific question could be to store your variable within an object and only provide access through getter / setter, then you can do what you want in the setter. e.g.

```
function data() {
    var foo = 0;

    this.setFoo = function(newVal) {
        foo = newVal;
        alert(foo);
    };
}

var theData = new data();

theData.setFoo(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. You cannot make a "variable watcher". There is no event fired for variables when they are changed.

What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
http://higginsforpresident.net/js/static/jq.pubsub.js

See
http://weblog.bocoup.com/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events

Or use a framework like backbone/underscore or knockout.js.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML/Elements/audio](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio#Media_Events)

```
    var foo;
    $(foo).bind('error', function() {     
       //your code here
    });
```